# Accessing elements from another view controller comes up nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I have an alert view that i made using **presentr** from GitHub. I used a simple `view controller` that will overlay over the current view controller. Now i have elements such as a `UIImage` and a `UIlabel` from the `first view controller` that needs to be accessed by the `alert view controller`. But when I click a unbutton in the `alert view controller` to access the `uiimage` and `text` from `uilabel` from the firstviewcontroller. Here is the code. Can you show me how I can fix this. I can't segue the data because I'm presenting the view controller and the data I'm trying to access is too much too segue anyway. I keep getting this error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" overtime i click the save button in `alertviewcontroller`.

```
class firstviewcontroller: UIViewController{
    var photos2: [ImageSource]?
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UIlabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Image: UIImage!
}

class alertviewcontroller: UIViewController{
    @IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let firstViewController: firstviewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstviewcontroller") as! firstviewcontroller

        if let image = firstViewController.Image { 
            imageview.image = image
        }
        if let label = firstViewController.Label {
            label.text = Label.text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating the alertViewController? If you are doing it using a storyboard, then the standard way to pass data to the child VC is through a segue.

Comment: As an aside, by convention, all classes start with an uppercase letter, and all instances start with a lowercase letter. Your code is very confusing because both the class and instance are `firstviewcontroller`. The class should be called `Firstviewcontroller` to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest mistake you're making is that you are creating a new instance of `firstviewcontroller` instead of just accessing the current one.

```
class alertviewcontroller: UIViewController{
    @IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let firstViewController: firstviewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstviewcontroller") as! firstviewcontroller // This is the mistake

        if let image = firstViewController.Image { 
            imageview.image = image
        }
        if let label = firstViewController.Label {
            label.text = Label.text
        }
    }
}
```

What you should do instead is access the `presentingViewController` since you presented the `alertviewcontroller` using the `present` function

The code would look like this

```
class alertviewcontroller: UIViewController{
    @IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        // NOTE: only do implicit unwrapping `as!` if you're sure that the value you're unwrapping is not `nil` or it is of the correct `data type` cause it might cause your app to crash
        let firstViewController: firstviewcontroller = self.presentingViewController as! firstviewcontroller

        if let image = firstViewController.Image { 
            imageview.image = image
        }
        if let label = firstViewController.Label {
            label.text = Label.text
        }
    }
}
```

**Tip**: Please review Swift coding guidelines since there are some minor mistakes regarding your naming of `methods`, `variables`, and `classes`.

Answer (score 0):

Might I am wrong but after review your code I have found this messing statement

```
let firstViewController: firstviewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstviewcontroller") as! firstviewcontroller
```

In this statement you are creating a new instance of `firstviewcontroller` not accessing already created instance of `firstviewcontroller`.

Next, you said

> I used a simple view controller that will overlay over the current
>   view controller

So I have assumed you didn't present or push `alertviewcontroller` on current viewController, on that behave I suggest you the following solutions

1. In `alertviewcontroller` get the instance of topViewController by using this method

   ```
   class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
       if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
           return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
       }
       if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
           if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
               return topViewController(base: selected)
           }
       }
       if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
           return topViewController(base: presented)
       }
       return base
   }
   ```

then you can transfer your data from `alertviewcontroller` to topViewController.

2. Next solution is that you can pass values from `alertviewcontroller` to `firstviewcontroller` by using delegates.